# Publishing message to Pub/Sub after Dataflow template job done

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I want to publish a message to a Pub/Sub topic once my Dataflow job has successfully completed.

I am doing this by using `wait_until_finish()` and then publishing a message once I have confirmed the pipeline has completed (has a current state of `JOB_STATE_DONE`). When I execute the pipeline locally (using either `DirectRunner` or `DataflowRunner`), I have the desired results. However, when I deploy this pipeline to a template and then create a job from a template, the code outside of `p.run()` does not get executed.

Here's the end of my pipeline

```
    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()
    publish_job_completion(result, all_pipeline_options)
```

Where `publish_job_completion` confirms that the job is done and publishes the message.

How can I design a pipeline that will publish to Pub/Sub once it is complete, even when run from a template?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a good way to do this via the template pipeline itself. However, you could wrap this into a simple Airflow DAG that runs on [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/). Airflow has a [DataflowTemplateOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.html) that can launch a Dataflow Template job as well as a [PubsubPublishOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/pubsub_operator.html) that can publish a message to Pub/Sub. You can string those two operations together as a simple DAG deployed to Cloud Composer.

While [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/cloud-composer-examples/composer_dataflow_examples) doesn't use a templated Dataflow job, it provides a good example of how Cloud Composer can be used to orchestrate Dataflow jobs.